# Крашится программа с ассемблерной вставкой

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, ассемблер, visual-studio-2010

При выполнении этого кода получаю следующую ошибку:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'C' was
>   corrupted.

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

#define SIZE_ROW 1000
#define SIZE_COLUMN 8

#ifndef BYTE
#define BYTE
typedef unsigned char byte;
#endif

void init(byte* A)
{
    for (long long int i = 0; i < (SIZE_ROW * SIZE_COLUMN); i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand() + 5*i + 9;
    }
}

void MyAsm(byte* A, byte* B, byte* C, byte k)
{

    byte lastRes = 0;

    _asm
    {
        pusha

        ;init
        mov ecx, SIZE_ROW*SIZE_COLUMN
        xor esi, esi

    loop1:
        mov bl, byte ptr B[esi]
        mov al, k
        mov dl, byte ptr C[esi]

        imul dl ;k*C
        add al, bl  ;b+k*C

        mov byte ptr A[esi], al
        mov lastRes, al

        inc esi
        loop loop1

        popa
    }

    std::cout << ("Последний результат из ассемблера: " + std::to_string((long long)lastRes));

}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    byte A[SIZE_ROW * SIZE_COLUMN], B[SIZE_ROW * SIZE_COLUMN], C[SIZE_ROW * SIZE_COLUMN];

    byte k = 2;

    init(B);
    init(C);

    MyAsm(A, B, C, k);

    return 0;
}
```

При этом если поместить тело функции MyAsm в main(), то всё нормально работает. В чем может быть ошибка и как ее исправить?

Компилятор: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professtional
ОС: Windows 10 Pro x64

Сама задача: вычислить значение выражения A = B + k*C, где k - постоянный коэффециент, а A, B, C - матрицы одинаковых размеров. При этом нужно сделать через ассемблерную вставку.

Comment: Отладчиком воспользоваться - не путь джедая?

Comment: Кстати, не подумал, что он будет работать для asm вставок. Да и как бы он помог мне? Я понимал, что что-то не то с обращением к массиву. На этом мое понимание заканчивалось.
P.S. VStudio показываем значение регистров, если их просто прописать как имена переменных (подразумевается, что вы находитесь внутри asm вставки)

Comment: Помог бы он очень просто: в отладчике сразу можно увидеть что именно записывается в регистр вместо  желаемого.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Инструкции типа

```
mov byte ptr A[esi], al
```

записывают данные в память самой локальной переменной `A` со смещением `esi`. То есть это даже близко не является записью в память, указуемую указателем `A` (как вы, очевидно, хотели). В результате вместо доступа к своим массивам вы разрушаете значение `A`, а затем и стек вашей функции `MyAsm`.

Чтобы доступиться к памяти массива, переданного через указатель `A`, вам надо прочитать содержимое `A` в регистр и адресоваться уже от него. Аналогично со всеми остальными указателями.

То есть если делать "в лоб" то например так

```
mov edi, B
mov bl, byte ptr [edi + esi]
mov edi, C
mov dl, byte ptr [edi + esi]
...
mov edi, A
mov byte ptr [edi + esi], al
```

Разумеется, аккуратно манипулируя регистрами, вы можете избежать постоянного чтения значений `A`, `B` и `С` из памяти.

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, пример кода для того, что вы написали?

Comment: Большое спасибо!